# How to define XPATH value as a variable inside html_nodes in rvest in R

Tags: r, xpath, rvest

while web scraping using R (rvest), I need to define the XPATH value as a variable inside html_nodes. so that I can iterate over many number of XPATHs. When I define XPATH outside, it throws error (For example error comes when xpath = //*[@id="banner"]). Could you please help.
My Code:

```
xpath <- as.character('//*[@id="title-overview-widget"]')
      name <- lego %>% 
      html_nodes(xpath) %>%
      html_text()
Error Message : Error in tokenize(css) : Unexpected character '/' found at position 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`html_nodes` has three parameters: the document, a css selector, and an xpath selector. By using it in a `%>%` chain, you are filling the first parameter with the document, but then you are setting the second parameter which is the css selector (which is why the error message is CSS related), not the xpath selector. You should use a named parameter to get around this problem

```
name <- lego %>% 
      html_nodes(xpath=xpath) %>%
      html_text()
```